# Could not find matching close tag for "<%" in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have the following code.

```
var days=JSON.parse(item.days)
var day=["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"]
<% day.map((item)>={
   <% day.map((item)>={
         if(days.find(item)>=0) { %>
            <input type="checkbox" value="<%= item %>" checked />                    
            <% } 
         else
            { %>
            <input type="checkbox" value="<%= item %>"  />
            <% } %>
            ) %>
```

I get the following error:
Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%"

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes like map is use for creating new array from existing array or modify it variable declaration is like below in **ejs**

```
<% var days=["Mon","Sun"]; %>
<% var day=["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"] %>
<% for(var item of day){%>
    <% if(days.includes(item)){%>
        <input type="checkbox" value="<%= item %>" checked /><%= item %>
    <%}else{%>
         <input type="checkbox" value="<%= item %>"/><%= item %>
    <%}%>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<%` is the syntax of EJS and can be used on `.ejs` file format. You should configuration the NodeJS server by set the `view engine`, add the code below:

```
 app.set("view engine", "ejs")
```